# Comparing columns in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns with data, column A and column B. I need to know how to check the data in column A and if any of that data does not exist in column B, I need the cell from column A that has the data not found in column B to display in column C. This seems like a simple problems, however those seem to be the ones I am unable to figure out.

Here is the code I have tried. I am rather sure there is a way to do this with a formula but I have given it an hour and a half and I am just stuck here. Apologies for a basic question I just have very little experience writing VBA code. Starting to not like it very much

```
Sub SBR()

Dim rng as Range

For Each rng in Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A50")
If rng <> Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B50") Then
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1") = rng
End If
next rng

End Sub
```

Comment: why did you tag python, java, javascript, and jquery when you're using VBA? Fixed the tags for you

Comment: They demanded tags!! I just wanted to move forward. I don't mind to add tags but if I only need 1 then I have no idea what else to put so I just added random tags

Comment: All good, .. `excel` and `vba` seem to fit the purpose don't you think?

Comment: Yes my apologies. Thank you for fixing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created two solutions for you, one to fit your scenario most and isn't as friendly to processing speed if you'd increase the size of the range:

```
Sub SBR()
    Dim rng As Range, rngB As Range, t
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rngB = .Range("B1:B50")
        For Each rng In .Range("A1:A50")
            
            If IsError(Application.Match(rng, rngB, 0)) Then 'check if it's in the B-range
                rng.Offset(, 2) = rng 'this will not empty a cell in c-column if it is found now but was missing before
            End If '.Offset(,2) = 2 columns further but same row
        Next rng
    End With
End Sub
```

The following one works with arrays and is faster (but with the size of this range, it really won't be felt)

```
Sub SBR_V2()
    Dim arr, rngA As Range, rngB As Range, i As Long, arrA, arrPrint, lRow As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngA = .Range("A1").Resize(lRow) 'A1:A50 in your case if there are only 50 values in column A
        Set rngB = .Range("B1").Resize(lRow) 'B1:B50
    End With
    arrA = rngA.Value 'All the A-column values in an array for quicker processing
    arr = Application.Match(rngA, rngB, 0) 'checking in one go if there are any missing values, missing gives an error
    ReDim arrPrint(1 To lRow, 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        If IsError(arr(i, 1)) Then 'missing
            arrPrint(i, 1) = arrA(i, 1) 'get the A-column value
        End If
    Next i
    rngA.Offset(, 2) = arrPrint 'place all the missing values in the C-column, this will overwrite cells that aren't missing with empty cells
End Sub
```

Hope you can like it a bit more again :)
If you've got any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Either of these showed only values that were in column A but not in column B. They both just replicated the entire list. I just don't know how something like this can be so steep in syntax. How on earth am I not able to see if a value in one column does not exist in another column. I feel like this should be an excel 101 function. I could do it with python or php in 30 seconds.

Comment: Isn't this what you're looking for? It looks if a value in column A does not exist in column B and puts value A in column C? Also, it is perfectly possible to do it with an excel formula too.

Comment: I was pretty sure it could be. I just cannot seem make it happen.

Comment: Have you adjusted my code in any way? Because it worked as intended on my end. The first one not deleting C-values if it was found, only adjusting if it wasn't. The second one only keeping the values in the C-column of the A-values which weren't found in B.

Comment: My apologies. I am sure your code is correct. The example I gave is not the true example. Also there is a great deal going on with this project. It is getting data from here and there scraping the web and running queries. I assume I am making some other error or it is a data type issue somewhere that is causing this to not work. Thank you again for your help. I apologize for commenting that it doesn't work. I was just looking for the simple version of a solution so that I could alter it to work for my situation.

Comment: Ok.. So if your example isn't the true example, can you edit your question so we can work with the true example and get to a more fitting answer? I don't know how to help you if you don't give me the correct information.

Comment: Your code did exactly what it was supposed to do. I had it checking one column that were actually hyperlinks with identifiers. I knew there was a reason why both of those code segments duplicated the entire list. It was doing what it was intended to do. Honestly I am very grateful for your help , but really I just need to pay closer attention before I ask a question. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad it did work out then. Asking the right question can be a bit tricky if you're not sure _why_ something isn't working and if things look the same. You're welcome and good luck further with your project :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a simple `=Match()` function:

```
=MATCH(B1,A$1:A$3,0)
```

Hereby a screenshot: you clearly see an error message, next to the third case, meaning that 'c' is not found in "B" column:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You were all right I was just not seeing my problem. I had tried this and many other variations of this and it wouldn't work. The reason is because the data was in fact all not a match and I overlooked it. I had it looking in a column that was hyperlinks with identifiers. This solution does work as well. Just the added step in the D column that says if the value in c <> 1, A1. Thank you again and sorry to have made such a blunder on my end.

Comment: @Mike: no problem. As my answer was useful for solving your issue, you might upvote it.

Comment: I actually tried to, I do not have the status here to do so. When I am able to in the future I will upvote both answers